# delete duplicated rows based on conditions pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete rows in dataframe if (x1, x2, x3) are the same between different rows and save in variable all ids of the rows deleted.

For example, with this data, I want to delete the second row;

```
d = {'id': ["i1", "i2", "i3", "i4"], 'x1': [13, 13, 61, 61], 'x2': [10, 10, 13, 13], 'x3': [12, 12, 2, 22], 'x4': [24, 24,9, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['x2','x3','x4'])`?

Comment: but how can i save the ids of deleted rows?

Comment: `deleted_ids = df.loc[df.duplicated(['x2','x3','x4']), 'id']`?

Comment: @QuangHoang no no thank you but the duplicates is x1&x2&x3. Please see my example

Comment: Then pass in `['x1','x2','x3']` instead of `['x2','x3','x4']`?

Comment: @charles You just have to pass in the columns list which you want to compare in the subset arg for `df.drop_duplicates()`. Optionally you can use `keep='first'`. Where do you want to store the deleted ids?

Answer (score 0):

```
#input data
d = {'id': ["i1", "i2", "i3", "i4"], 'x1': [13, 13, 61, 61], 'x2': [10, 10, 13, 13], 'x3': [12, 12, 2, 22], 'x4': [24, 24,9, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#create new column where contents from x1, x2 and x3 columns are merged
df['MergedColumn'] = df[df.columns[1:4]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)

#remove duplicates based on the created column and drop created column
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.drop_duplicates("MergedColumn", keep='first').drop(columns="MergedColumn"))

#print output dataframe
print(df1)

#merge two dataframes
df2 = pd.merge(df, df1,  how='left', on = 'id')
#find rows with null values in the right table (rows that were removed)
df2 = df2[df2['x1_y'].isnull()]

#prints ids of rows that were removed
print(df2['id'])
```